# How to diff in "diff -Nru" format for git?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I'm working on a fork of an open-source project, and have made some changes that I'd like to submit upstream (those changes are on separate branches, so as not to conflict with any fork-specific changes that I've made and don't plan on submitting upstream).

Only problem, though: the project maintainers require that all patches be submitted in `diff -Nru` format. (their "git repository" is merely a `git-svn` mirror of their SVN repository)

Is there any easy way to make a patch like this using git, short of checking out a second copy of the repository and just running `diff -Nru`?

I'm running Windows, if that makes a difference, but I do have `diff` and `patch` [(from the MAME development tools package)](http://www.mamedev.org/tools/) installed, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Have you tried `git format-patch`?...

Comment: I think the standard `git diff` output is pretty much in that format already.  It produces recursive (`-r`) diffs with context (`-u`).  I don't know whether or not you get the `-N` behavior, but it is unlikely to matter unless you have deleted files.